# VueJS 3, better way to access Vuex store variable in router?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, router, store

With Vue.js3, I have successfully logged into Google Firebase authentication in one component, then stored the Firebase user variable in the Vuex store using:

```
 store.commit('setUser', userData);
```

After that, I was able to accesse it in another component:

```
const currentUser = computed(() => store.getters.currentUser);
```

However, I am unable to retrieve this user variable in the router.js file using the above method.
My current workaround is to create an action for the store, an asynchronous fetchUser function like this. It continuously attempts to retrieve the Firebase user variable, commits it, and returns. Without the promise timer setTimeout, it will immediately return Null value, even if I use async await.

```
// store/index.js

import { createStore } from 'vuex';

const store = createStore({
  state: {
    user: null,
   
  },
  mutations: {
    setUser(state, user) {
      state.user = user;
    },
  
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchUser({ commit }) {
      try {
        let fetchedUser = this.getters.currentUser;
        let elapsedTime = 0;
        const maxWaitTime = 10000; // 10 seconds
       
        while (!fetchedUser && elapsedTime < maxWaitTime) {
          fetchedUser = this.getters.currentUser;
          elapsedTime += 200;
          await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 50));
        }

        if (!fetchedUser) {
         
          throw new Error('Timeout: Unable to fetch user within 10 seconds.');
        }
     
        commit('setUser', fetchedUser);
        return fetchedUser;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user:', error);
        throw error; 
      }
    },

  },
  getters: {
    currentUser: state => state.user,

  },
});

export default store;
```

My router.js file:

```
const routes = [ 
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'HomePage',
    component: HomePage,
    beforeEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
      const store = useStore();

      try {     
        await store.dispatch('fetchUser');       
        const currentUser =  await store.state.user;    
        if (!currentUser) {        
        // redirect to GoogleLogin page
          next({ name: 'GoogleLogin' });
        } else {
        // Stay at homepage
          next();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user:', error);       
        next();
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'GoogleLogin',
    component: GoogleLogin    
  },
  ];
```

While this workaround works, it has terrible performance, Normally it takes 800 ms to fetch.
Yes, alternatively, I can add another onAuthStateChanged to the Router.js or push a router.push at the onAuthStateChanged of the Main.js to check and redirect the login page.

```
 firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged((userData) => {      
          store.commit('setUser', userData);
          console.log('Login check: ', userData);
          if (!userData) {   
            router.push('/login'); // in main.js file

            //next({ name: 'GoogleLogin' }); // if use in router.js
          } else {    

            //...
          }
        });
```

But sometimes, I still require Vuex variables to use in Router.js, so how can I improve this, or are there better methods for utilizing Vuex global variables in the Router file?

Comment: Polling isn't wanted or needed here. It's unclear where state.user is set. In your code setUser is called only inside fetchUser, and it waits for state.user to set it. Depending on how it's supposed to work, you may still need onAuthStateChanged but you need to keep the store in sync with auth state, i.e set state.user to updated user data

Comment: @Estus Flask, I currently set the state.user inside firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged((userData) => {store.commit('setUser', userData)}) in the main.js file. I only call onAuthStateChanged once in the main.js file to set the user variable to the store and then use it globally."

Answer (score 1):

For me, using Vuex store into router.js is the best way, because it is the most straightforward way to directly import and use it to access the state.

```
import store from './store'; // Import your Vuex store

   router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
     const currentUser = store.getters.currentUser;
     if (!currentUser) {
       next({ name: 'GoogleLogin' });
     } else {
       next();
     }
   });
```

Comment: I am not sure why but this store.getters.currentUser returns null

Comment: @ThiHoang This is generally the correct way. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if the problem persists. Based on the logic in the question, currentUser cannot be null because of this, `if (!userData) {   router.push('/login')`

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this, but as far as I can see, store.getters.currentUser won't work because of synchronous here. This implies that retrieving the currentUser takes some time, and before it is set, its value is Null.

I have successfully made it work in the router.js file without the bottleneck caused by passive setTimeOut waiting, using this:

```
watchEffect(() => { 
console.log("user value:", store.state.user)
});
```

The Chrome console shows 2 lines:

```
user value: Null 
user value: [expected firebase user].
```

I don't know how, but it provides what I need, and I'm satisfied with the result, so I have moved on to the next step